# Is there any way to call a Mocha function including it() and run whatever is inside `it`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to call a Mocha function as simple as bellow

```
this.logSomething = function() {
    console.log('======== outside it ========')
    it('something inside it', function logSomething(done){
        console.log('+++++++ something inside it ++++++++') 
        done()  
    })
}
```

from another js file.
After using `mocha.run(logSomething())`

```
======== outside it ========
```

appears but

```
+++++++ something inside it ++++++++
```

is missing.

I have tried using 'describe' but the result is the same. Any solutions instead of bypasses?

FYI, I know it can be run by importing it as a Mocha test and using Mocha CLI, however I want to use this method to rerun the failed functions from my test suite, therefore it could be zero or many functions with different names and it's not the simple as importing certain number of Mocha tests.

Also, I have tried Mocha's existing retry and since it doesn't match our tests, I'm not using it.

Comment: I think you want `mocha.run(logSomething)` instead... (notice that the function isn't called. I doubt you intend to run the function before passing it to `mocha.run`)

Comment: Thanks @GarrettMotzner, but it has the same behavior.

Comment: See https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha.js#L794-L850. So `run` takes a callback that is called when _finished_, so we actually don't want to pass anything to `run`. Calling your `logSomething` function before calling `run` looks like it will register a test, and then that test will run when `run` is called, although caching can affect this, and the runner can also affect this. So I suspect that your runner is not configured how you expect, or a similar issue.

Comment: Also, I assume you are running these tests in node, not the browser, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm running all in node

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Actually, I'm using this to be able to rerun the failed tests by Mocha. As you mentioned, since `logSomething` is registered as a test, I won't be able to somehow rerun the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A simple example

Exporting your `logSomething` function, importing it into another file and executing it does give me the behavior you expect:

**lib.js**

```
module.exports.logSomething = function() {
    console.log('======== outside it ========')
    it('something inside it', function logSomething(done){
        console.log('+++++++ something inside it ++++++++')
        done()
    })
}
```

**test.js**

```
const {logSomething} = require('./lib');
logSomething();
logSomething();
```

**Output**

```
$ mocha test.js
======== outside it ========
======== outside it ========


+++++++ something inside it ++++++++
  ✓ something inside it
+++++++ something inside it ++++++++
  ✓ something inside it

  2 passing (4ms)
```

## An example with multiple files and classes

So here's a more sophisticated example: There's one `test.js`, which imports two classes from two separate files. Each class has two methods that, in turn, run mocha test cases using `it()`.

**test.js**

```
const {TestSet1} = require('./lib1');
const {TestSet2} = require('./lib2');

new TestSet1().runTest1();
new TestSet1().runTest2();
new TestSet2().runTest1();
new TestSet2().runTest2();
```

**lib1.js**

```
class TestSet1 {

    runTest1() {
        it('should run TestSet1.Test1.It1', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet1.Test1.It1');
        });
        it('should run TestSet1.Test1.It2', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet1.Test1.It2');
        });
    }

    runTest2() {
        it('should run TestSet1.Test2.It1', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet1.Test2.It1');
        });
        it('should run TestSet1.Test2.It2', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet1.Test2.It2');
        });
    }

}

module.exports = {TestSet1};
```

**lib2.js**

```
class TestSet2 {

    runTest1() {
        it('should run TestSet2.Test1.It1', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet2.Test1.It1');
        });
        it('should run TestSet2.Test1.It2', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet2.Test1.It2');
        });
    }

    runTest2() {
        it('should run TestSet2.Test2.It1', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet2.Test2.It1');
        });
        it('should run TestSet2.Test2.It2', () => {
            console.log('This is output from TestSet2.Test2.It2');
        });
    }

}

module.exports = {TestSet2};
```

**Output**

```
$ mocha test.js


This is output from TestSet1.Test1.It1
  ✓ should run TestSet1.Test1.It1
This is output from TestSet1.Test1.It2
  ✓ should run TestSet1.Test1.It2
This is output from TestSet1.Test2.It1
  ✓ should run TestSet1.Test2.It1
This is output from TestSet1.Test2.It2
  ✓ should run TestSet1.Test2.It2
This is output from TestSet2.Test1.It1
  ✓ should run TestSet2.Test1.It1
This is output from TestSet2.Test1.It2
  ✓ should run TestSet2.Test1.It2
This is output from TestSet2.Test2.It1
  ✓ should run TestSet2.Test2.It1
This is output from TestSet2.Test2.It2
  ✓ should run TestSet2.Test2.It2

  8 passing (9ms)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works in this simple case, however I need to expand it for 100s of functions with different names and all have related (unrelated) functionalities, therefore having so many js files won't be helpful and would be so confusing.

Comment: You can easily scale this: Export multiple functions from one file. Wrap them in classes and export these. And so on.

Comment: So I expect to see the same result when using 
`module.exports = function() { 
this.logSomething = function(){}
this.doSomethingElse = function(){}
...`

Comment: I added a more comprehensive example to my answer. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Each time you add a comment or an example, I learn something new. :) I implemented the method you just mentioned, and it runs the tests with no issues, however, my question is regarding the retry function which is going to retry the failed tests as functions. The retry is not able to run `it()` probably Mocha doesn't allow rerunning 'it()'.